# Why changing order of start locations would result into different solution?

Tags: or-tools

I have a case, where routes shall be starting from specific start locations and end into one location.

I found that the locations array that has all the nodes (including the start locations and end location), I found that the start locations order does matter with respect to the solution.

To make it easier to explain, here is the solution when I insert the start location right after the a close node:
[image: start locations sorted]

and here is the solution when I swap the start locations order in the locations list:
[image: start locations with different order]

No matter what strategy I used, as I have explained in here:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HvW0Epubic)

[[image: Video thumbnail]

on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBa0YR6XXiI)

I get the solution as:

```
routes = []
for vehicle_nbr in range(num_routes):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_nbr)
    route = []
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        node_index= routing.IndexToNode(index)
        route.append(node_index)
        index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))      
    route.append(routing.IndexToNode(index))
    routes.append(route)
return routes
```

Any idea?